# Cannot get a QAbstractListModel subclass working on PySide2 without a hack

Tags: python, pyside2

Using the work-in-progress PySide2 (to be able to use Qt5), I have the following code:

**main.qml:**

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    ListView {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        model: listModel
        delegate: Text {
            text: model.name
        }
    }
}
```

**main.py:**

```py
from sys import argv, exit

from PySide2.QtCore import QAbstractListModel
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


class TaskListModel(QAbstractListModel):

    _COLUMNS = ('name',)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == self._COLUMNS.index('name'):
            return str(index.row())
        return None

    def roleNames(self):
        return dict(enumerate(self._COLUMNS))

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return 1


app = QGuiApplication(argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('listModel', None)
engine.load('main.qml')
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('listModel', TaskListModel())
exit(app.exec_())
```

The 3 method calls on the `engine` object towards the end of **main.py** are the way they are because:

1. I get `Unable to assign [undefined] to QString` if I use:

   ```py
   engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('listModel', TaskListModel())
   engine.load('main.qml')
   ```
2. I get `ReferenceError: listModel is not defined` if I use:

   ```py
   engine.load('main.qml')
   engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('listModel', TaskListModel())
   ```

Is my way the only way to do this properly? Shouldn't the code in my first bullet above work as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `PySide2` removes `TaskListModel()` from memory if you assign it to some variable, I have found 2 solutions:

- Create a variable that stores the model:

---

```
app = QGuiApplication(argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
model = TaskListModel()
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('listModel', model)
engine.load('main.qml')
exit(app.exec_())
```

- Pass a parent to the model:

---

```
app = QGuiApplication(argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('listModel', TaskListModel(engine))
engine.load('main.qml')
exit(app.exec_())
```